# Default value for select input doesn't appear, the select field is empty with Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a dropdown select, and using several css to remove some of the default look. But somehow when I load the page, the select field is empty, but it should show the default value. I can't make it work.

```
<select v-model="order.billing.address.country" :disabled="form" v-validate="'required'" name="country">
  <option selected disabled>{{$t('country')}}</option>
  <option value="AT">{{$t('AT')}}</option>
  <option value="BE">{{$t('BE')}}</option>
</select

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
```

can any of this make the problem, or the HTML part is wrong? I'm only having problem with the default value, after selecting something it works.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `v-model`, the `selected` in the DOM won't matter. The `<select>` will have as selected whatever value the `v-model` points to.

To have that `<option>` as selected, give it a value and set `order.billing.address.country` to it.

Example:

```js
// somewhere in the code
order.billing.address.country = -1;
```

```html
<select v-model="order.billing.address.country" :disabled="form" v-validate="'required'" name="country">
  <option value="-1" disabled>{{$t('country')}}</option>
  <option value="AT">{{$t('AT')}}</option>
  <option value="BE">{{$t('BE')}}</option>
</select
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: what is the expected default value, an empty string or the first option?

**If empty string:** you can update the first option to have a default value of empty.

```
<option value="" disabled>{{$t('country')}}</option>
```

**If the first option** which is:

```
<option value="AT">{{$t('AT')}}</option>
```

Remove:

```
<option value="-1" disabled>{{$t('country')}}</option>
```

And that should work I guess. If not then you have to trigger change on your select element to register the value.